# changing a do while loop to a while loop in a tic tac toe game

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop, do-while

can anyone help me convert this do-while loop into a while loop? I've tried but can't seem to switch without many errors. Thanks!

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String ch;
    TicTacToe Toe = new TicTacToe();
    do {
        Toe.newBoard();
        Toe.play();
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again (Enter 'yes')? ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ch = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("ch value is " + ch);
    } while (ch.equals("yes"));
}
```

Here's the full code for the tic-tac-toe game in console:
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class TicTacToe {
    private int tic;
    private char tac[] = new char[10];
    private char player;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String ch;
        TicTacToe Toe = new TicTacToe();
        do {
            Toe.newBoard();
            Toe.play();
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again (Enter 'yes')? ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            ch = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("ch value is " + ch);
        } while (ch.equals("yes"));
    }
    public void newBoard() {
        char posndef[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
        int i;
        tic = 0;
        player = 'X';
        for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            tac[i] = posndef[i];
        currentBoard();
    }
    public String currentBoard() {
        System.out.println(" \t\t     |    | ");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "  " + tac[1] + "  | " + tac[2] + "  | " + tac[3]);
        System.out.println(" \t\t ____|____|____ ");
        System.out.println(" \t\t     |    | ");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "  " + tac[4] + "  | " + tac[5] + "  | " + tac[6]);
        System.out.println(" \t\t ____|____|____ ");
        System.out.println(" \t\t     |    | ");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "  " + tac[7] + "  | " + tac[8] + "  | " + tac[9]);
        System.out.println(" \t\t     |    | ");
        return "currentBoard";
    }
    public void play() {
        int spot;
        char blank = ' ';
        System.out.println("Player " + getPlayer() + " will go first and be the letter 'X'");
        do {
            System.out.println("\n\n Player " + getPlayer() + " choose a position.");
            boolean posTaken = true;
            while (posTaken) {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                spot = in.nextInt();
                posTaken = checkPosn(spot);
                if (posTaken == false)
                    tac[spot] = getPlayer();
            }
            System.out.println("Nice move.");
            currentBoard();
            nextPlayer();
        } while (checkWinner() == blank);
    }
    public char checkWinner() {
        char Winner = ' ';
        if (tac[1] == 'X' && tac[2] == 'X' && tac[3] == 'X')
            Winner = 'X';
        if (tac[4] == 'X' && tac[5] == 'X' && tac[6] == 'X')
            Winner = 'X';
        if (tac[7] == 'X' && tac[8] == 'X' && tac[9] == 'X')
            Winner = 'X';
        if (tac[1] == 'X' && tac[4] == 'X' && tac[7] == 'X')
            Winner = 'X';
        if (tac[2] == 'X' && tac[5] == 'X' && tac[8] == 'X')
            Winner = 'X';
        if (tac[3] == 'X' && tac[6] == 'X' && tac[9] == 'X')
            Winner = 'X';
        if (tac[1] == 'X' && tac[5] == 'X' && tac[9] == 'X')
            Winner = 'X';
        if (tac[3] == 'X' && tac[5] == 'X' && tac[7] == 'X')
            Winner = 'X';
        if (Winner == 'X') {
            System.out.println("Player1 wins the game.");
            return Winner;
        }
        if (tac[1] == 'O' && tac[2] == 'O' && tac[3] == 'O')
            Winner = 'O';
        if (tac[4] == 'O' && tac[5] == 'O' && tac[6] == 'O')
            Winner = 'O';
        if (tac[7] == 'O' && tac[8] == 'O' && tac[9] == 'O')
            Winner = 'O';
        if (tac[1] == 'O' && tac[4] == 'O' && tac[7] == 'O')
            Winner = 'O';
        if (tac[2] == 'O' && tac[5] == 'O' && tac[8] == 'O')
            Winner = 'O';
        if (tac[3] == 'O' && tac[6] == 'O' && tac[9] == 'O')
            Winner = 'O';
        if (tac[1] == 'O' && tac[5] == 'O' && tac[9] == 'O')
            Winner = 'O';
        if (tac[3] == 'O' && tac[5] == 'O' && tac[7] == 'O')
            Winner = 'O';
        if (Winner == 'O') {
            System.out.println("Player2 wins the game.");
            return Winner;
        }
        // check for Tie
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            if (tac[i] == 'X' || tac[i] == 'O') {
                if (i == 9) {
                    char Draw = 'D';
                    System.out.println(" Tied Game ");
                    return Draw;
                }
                continue;
            } else
                break;
        }
        return Winner;
    }
    public boolean checkPosn(int spot) {
        if (tac[spot] == 'X' || tac[spot] == 'O') {
            System.out.println("That position is already taken, please choose another");
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void nextPlayer() {
        if (player == 'X')
            player = 'O';
        else
            player = 'X';
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return "Tic Tac Toe";
    }
    public char getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you tried for the `while` loop.  Otherwise we don't know what you're doing wrong

Comment: public static void main(String args[]) {
  String ch;
  TicTacToe Toe = new TicTacToe();
  while (ch.equals("yes")){
   Toe.newBoard();
   Toe.play();
   System.out.println("Would you like to play again (Enter 'yes')? ");
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   ch = in.nextLine();
   System.out.println("ch value is " + ch);
  }
 }

Comment: I don't know what to do with ch

Comment: Add a parameter to check if first time playing do a while that or the value `ch = yes`

So an example would be: `boolean firstPlay = true; while(firstPlay || ch.equals("yes")) { firstPlay = false; /*Rest of code*/}`

That should fix it

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you want to do this, but its as simple as making the `while` condition pass when the loop is reached:

```
String ch = "yes";
TicTacToe Toe = new TicTacToe();
while("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(ch)) {
    Toe.newBoard();
    Toe.play();
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again (Enter 'yes')? ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ch = in.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Hit the nail on the head.  To elaborate, you were comparing `ch`, which in your case was uninitialized, to `"yes"` which fails.  You need to initialize your loop condition so it passes at least once.

Comment: In response to Hill's comment, I've edited my answer to show the convention of using `equalsIgnoreCase` based on the literal string. You were probably having a `NullPointerException` when using `ch.equals` because it was not initialized.